# Estoy intentando hacer una operación lógica XOR en PHP con 2 strings y está me devuelve signos de interrogación

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer una operación lógica XOR en PHP con 2 strings y está me devuelve signos de interrogación, hice otros intentos pero con este en concreto no funciona alguien sabe alguna solución?.

$word = ('01001111100000000000000000000000' ^ '01001000010011110100110001000001');

Comment: Te recomiendo ser mas objetivo en tu pregunta, asi como añadir los intentos que mencionas y el codigo, te invito a dar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) saludos

Answer (score 0):

PHP no está tratando esos ceros y unos como binario, puedes para realizar la operación correctamente convertirlo a haxadecimal con base_convert por ejemplo

Ejemplo:

```
echo base_convert('01001111100000000000000000000000', 2, 16) ^ base_convert('01001000010011110100110001000001', 2, 16);


// Resultado: ^VS
```